# CFBundleShortVersionString, CFBundleVersion is missing when running library unit tests on simulator

Tags: swift, xcode

I create a swift library with some unit tests for that. In my Info.plist file

There I can see

- `Bundle version string, short = 1.0.0`
- `Bundle version = 123`

On my code I want to get this informations by

```
... Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
... Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
```

When I now execute the unit tests (I only can do this on simulators for libraries), I get the following:

- `Bundle version string, short = nil` (not included)
- `Bundle version = 14490.71`

But I expect to get `1.0` and `123`

Comment: Had any update since? Got a workaround to get these info while testing? I myself have some objects and logics that depend on that and I'd like a coverage of it 

Answer (score -3):

There are specific requirements for both `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion`.

**[CFBundleShortVersionString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleshortversionstring)**:

<sub>This key is a user-visible string for the version of the bundle. **The
required format is three period-separated integers, such as 10.14.1**.
The string can only contain numeric characters (0-9) and periods.</sub>

> <sub>Each integer provides information about the release in the format
>   **[Major].[Minor].[Patch]**:</sub>
>   • <sub>**Major**: A major revision number.
>
>   • **Minor**: A minor revision number.
>
>   • **Patch**: A maintenance release number.</sub>
>   <sub>This key is used throughout the system to identify the version of the
>   bundle.</sub>

---

**[CFBundleVersion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion)**:

<sub>**This key is a machine-readable string composed of one to three period-separated integers, such as 10.14.1.** The string can only contain numeric characters (0-9) and periods.</sub>

> <sub>Each integer provides information about the bundle version in the
>   format **[Major].[Minor].[Patch]**:
>
>   • **Major**: A major revision number.
>
>   • **Minor**: A minor revision number.
>
>   • **Patch**: A maintenance release number.</sub>
>   <sub>*You can include more integers but the system ignores them.*</sub>
>
> <sub>You can also abbreviate the version by using only one or two integers,
>   where missing integers in the format are interpreted as zeros. For
>   example, 0 specifies 0.0.0, 10 specifies 10.0.0, and 10.5 specifies
>   10.5.0.</sub>
>
> <sub>This key is required by the App Store and is used throughout the
>   system to identify your app's released or unreleased build. For macOS
>   apps, increment the version number before you distribute a
>   build.</sub>

So to sum it up, you aren't following the specification that is required for those property list keys.

Comment: You've right, but it doesn't matter for the case. `1.0.0 (123)` => `nil (14490.71)`